# Is it possible to access 4GB memory in v86 mode through the iret instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I know that iret instruction can execute in protected mode and return to v86 mode, while updating all segment registers (popping selectors from the current stack and writing them to segment registers), but will the descriptor cache for each segment register also be loaded with a new segment descriptor, or just the base field will be updated to selector*16? if new descriptors will be loaded, can I specify 4GB segments for programs running in v86 mode?

Comment: I believe it is not generally possible to access offsets beyond 64 KiB in a segment in V86 Mode (unlike Real 86 Mode).

Comment: I'd be extremely surprised if segment limits and attributes aren't forced to be real-mode compatible (64 KiB segment limits, read/write, etc) when switching to V86 mode (primarily because it'd be extremely broken if some segment limits were smaller than 64 KiB beforehand). Unfortunately I can't find anything in Intel's manual that explicitly states this.

Comment: @Brendan There is a special mode called ''unreal mode'', which first enters protected mode, changes the segment limit to 4GB, and then returns to real mode, thereby obtaining 4GB of memory space. So I guess v86 mode that is also entered from protected mode should have this mechanism too.